# Report Folder and Report Name Control (Validation? Workflow? Apex?)

Tags: reporting, administration, validation, business-logic, naming-convention

Is there a way to **control** (to any degree) the **naming conventions of Report Folders and Reports**?

*I'm not finding a solution via Google searches or Salesforce resources.*

---

Some examples:

**Block** create/edit of report/folder with certain prefixes by certain users/ profiles/ etc

   *(ex: IF LEFT(FolderName,3)="BAD" THEN ERROR)*

**Force** use of certain prefixes in report/folder name by certain users/ profiles/ etc

   *(ex: IF LEFT(FolderName,4)<>"GOOD" THEN ERROR)*

**Block** use of certain words in report/folder names

   *(ex: IF CONTAINS(foldername, "WRONG") THEN ERROR)*

---

**Info:**   This is mostly business-process based, but also, as the Sys Admin, my desire for ORDER within the Org, and not allowing users to put things into disarray.  **Naming conventions** are EXTREMELY important to me, from development to administration to folders on servers to day-to-day communications.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no, you can't do that. That being said, best practice is to NOT let users create folders. This practice is established for exactly the reason you mentioned.

As for reports. The report name shouldn't be controlled like that. The report name is not for the admin, its for the users who need the reports and the names need to make sense to those users. Users need to be able to find and understand the purposes of the report. Otherwise, the report has no benefits.

Comment: I agree that not letting users create folders is going to be the solution until I (optimistic, hah) figure out how to control what this Question says. . . . . . I do not agree that Report Name is for the "users" per se (to choose the name);  in their Personal folder, of course, do what they want;  in folders accessible by others?  No way.  I want it under tight control.  As it is, when a user comes up with a report we want others to use, they'll have to "submit it" to be maintained by someone who CAN put it in the public view given the (apparent) current limitations.  (sigh)

Comment: That "someone" is the admin (you I presume). That is one way to go but adds a big load of work to your workload.